# Scrollview inside viewpager in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Problem is that viewpager works but scrollview doesn't. ListView is populated asnycrounously, maybe this is problem so layout is not correctly measured. Anyway, this is layout of fragment( viewpager has two tabs, this is content of second tab:

```
    <ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout

      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="#EDEDED"
        tools:context="com.adriagate.onlineandroid.fragments.GuestsRegistrationFragment">
       <TextView
          android:id="@+id/guestsLabelGuestRegistration"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:paddingTop="24dp"
          android:text="Gosti"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

      <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
          android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutOfferedService"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@id/guestsLabelGuestRegistration"

          android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding10dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding10dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding10dp"
          android:background="@color/caldroid_white">

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="4dp"

          android:text="Vrsta usluge"
          android:textSize="12dp" />

      <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
          android:id="@+id/spinnerOfferedService"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="2dp"

          android:theme="@style/customSpinnerTheme" />
  </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
      android:id="@+id/textInputArrivalOrganizations"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@id/textInputLayoutOfferedService"
      android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding10dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding10dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding10dp"
      android:background="@color/caldroid_white">

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="4dp"
          android:text="Organizacija dolaska"
          android:textSize="12dp" />

      <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
          android:id="@+id/spinnerArrivalOrganization"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:clipToPadding="true"
          android:theme="@style/customSpinnerTheme" />
  </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/linearLayoutHoursGuestRegistrationWrapper"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@id/textInputArrivalOrganizations"
      android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding10dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding10dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding10dp"
      android:background="@color/caldroid_white">

      <RelativeLayout
          android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutArrivalHourGuestRegistrationFragment"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"

          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding5dp"
          android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding5dp">

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textViewArrivalHourGuestRegistrationFragment"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
              android:text="10:00"
              android:textSize="22dp" />

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textViewLabelArrivalHourGuestRegistrationFragment"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_below="@id/textViewArrivalHourGuestRegistrationFragment"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
              android:text="Sat dolaska"
              android:textColor="@color/gray_dark" />

      </RelativeLayout>

      <RelativeLayout
          android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutDepartureHourGuestRegistrationFragment"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"

          android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding5dp"
          android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding5dp">

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textViewDepartureHourGuestRegistrationFragment"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
              android:text="14:00"
              android:textSize="22dp" />

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textViewLabelDepartureHourGuestRegistrationFragment"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_below="@id/textViewDepartureHourGuestRegistrationFragment"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
              android:text="Sat odlaska"
              android:textColor="@color/gray_dark" />
      </RelativeLayout>


  </LinearLayout>

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/guestsRegisterOnEvisitorLabelGuestRegistration"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@id/linearLayoutHoursGuestRegistrationWrapper"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:paddingTop="24dp"
      android:text="Prijavi goste na eVisitor"
      android:textStyle="bold" />

  <ListView
      android:id="@+id/eVisitorGuestsList"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_below="@id/guestsRegisterOnEvisitorLabelGuestRegistration"
      android:layout_margin="10dp"

      android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
      android:background="@color/caldroid_white"
      android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
      android:divider="#CCCCCC"
      android:dividerHeight="1dp"
      android:paddingLeft="2dp"></ListView>

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/newGuestLabelGuestRegistration"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@id/eVisitorGuestsList"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:paddingTop="24dp"
      android:text="Unos novog gosts"
      android:textStyle="bold" />

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/scanDocumentLinearLayoutClickWrapper"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="25dp"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayoutHoursGuestRegistrationWrapper"
      android:layout_alignStart="@+id/linearLayoutHoursGuestRegistrationWrapper"
      android:layout_below="@+id/newGuestLabelGuestRegistration"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding10dp">

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/imageViewScanCardGuestRegistration"
          android:layout_width="25dp"
          android:layout_height="25dp"
          android:adjustViewBounds="true"
          android:background="@drawable/ic_image_white_48dp"
          android:backgroundTint="#d50000" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textViewScanCardGuestRegistration"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:allowUndo="false"
          android:text="Skeniraj osobnu iskaznicu"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
          android:textColor="#d50000" />
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/enterNewGuestLinearLayoutClickWrapper"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="25dp"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayoutHoursGuestRegistrationWrapper"
      android:layout_alignStart="@+id/linearLayoutHoursGuestRegistrationWrapper"
      android:layout_below="@+id/scanDocumentLinearLayoutClickWrapper"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding10dp">

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/imageViewEnterGuestRegistration"
          android:layout_width="25dp"
          android:layout_height="25dp"
          android:adjustViewBounds="true"
          android:background="@drawable/ic_create_black_48dp"
          android:backgroundTint="#d50000" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textViewEnterGuestRegistration"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:allowUndo="false"
          android:text="Upiši novog gosta"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
          android:textColor="#d50000" />
  </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is my activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorDirtyGray"
    tools:context=".activities.ReservationsAllActivity">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        tools:context=".activities.ReservationDetailsActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayoutReservationDetails"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

                android:id="@+id/toolbarReservationDetails"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"

                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
                android:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
                tools:title="Rezervacije">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewToolbarReservationDetails"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/caldroid_white"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    tools:text="Nova rezervacija" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progress_spinner_reservation_details4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:indeterminate="true"

                    android:visibility="gone" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <RelativeLayout

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewPagerReservationDetails"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tabLayoutReservationDetails"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:tabBackground="@color/caldroid_black"
                        app:tabGravity="fill"
                        app:tabMode="fixed"
                        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
                        app:tabTextColor="@color/caldroid_white" />
                </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

            </RelativeLayout>


        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<include layout="@layout/include_menu_navigation_view"></include>
<!--app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"-->
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Refer this solution :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/44017731/3946958

Comment: replace scrollview with NestedScrollView

Comment: Does not help, I can all my content now, except the fact that my listview now has only one item instead of four. Maybe I cannot have listview that is inside nestedscrollview that is insideviewpager?

Comment: add app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" in Nested Scrollview and Listview

Comment: It is the same as before...

Comment: post activity xml code

Comment: Your LinearLayouts should have android:orientation defined

Comment: app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" in both RelativeLayout and Viewpager and move Viewpager out of APPbarlayout and android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" in menifest

Comment: The only difference  now is that I don't see tabs.

Comment: did you add orientation in Linear layout as @AlexandreBOURETZ said

Comment: Yes, but nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solution. Putting NestedScrollView definitely helped in a way, but ListView showed only one item and others were visible only when I scrolled that small piece of UI( listview). So I decided to make not scrollable listview (because I relly want to display them and nested scroll view will do the scrolling of whole fragment). This is the code of NonScrollableListView:

```
public class NonScrollListView extends ListView {

    public NonScrollListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int heightMeasureSpec_custom = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec_custom);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
    }
}
```

Now listview shows all elements and also fragment is scrollable because of NestedScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `ListView` inside `ScrollView`. Use `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` to make it working.

**Try this:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="#EDEDED">

       <TextView
          android:id="@+id/guestsLabelGuestRegistration"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:paddingTop="24dp"
          android:text="Gosti"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

      <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
          android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutOfferedService"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@id/guestsLabelGuestRegistration"

          android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding10dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding10dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding10dp"
          android:background="@color/caldroid_white">

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="4dp"

          android:text="Vrsta usluge"
          android:textSize="12dp" />

      <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
          android:id="@+id/spinnerOfferedService"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="2dp"

          android:theme="@style/customSpinnerTheme" />
  </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
      android:id="@+id/textInputArrivalOrganizations"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@id/textInputLayoutOfferedService"
      android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding10dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding10dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding10dp"
      android:background="@color/caldroid_white">

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="4dp"
          android:text="Organizacija dolaska"
          android:textSize="12dp" />

      <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
          android:id="@+id/spinnerArrivalOrganization"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:clipToPadding="true"
          android:theme="@style/customSpinnerTheme" />
  </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/linearLayoutHoursGuestRegistrationWrapper"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@id/textInputArrivalOrganizations"
      android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding10dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding10dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding10dp"
      android:background="@color/caldroid_white">

      <RelativeLayout
          android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutArrivalHourGuestRegistrationFragment"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"

          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding5dp"
          android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding5dp">

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textViewArrivalHourGuestRegistrationFragment"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
              android:text="10:00"
              android:textSize="22dp" />

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textViewLabelArrivalHourGuestRegistrationFragment"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_below="@id/textViewArrivalHourGuestRegistrationFragment"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
              android:text="Sat dolaska"
              android:textColor="@color/gray_dark" />

      </RelativeLayout>

      <RelativeLayout
          android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutDepartureHourGuestRegistrationFragment"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"

          android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding5dp"
          android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding5dp">

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textViewDepartureHourGuestRegistrationFragment"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
              android:text="14:00"
              android:textSize="22dp" />

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textViewLabelDepartureHourGuestRegistrationFragment"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_below="@id/textViewDepartureHourGuestRegistrationFragment"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
              android:text="Sat odlaska"
              android:textColor="@color/gray_dark" />
      </RelativeLayout>


  </LinearLayout>

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/guestsRegisterOnEvisitorLabelGuestRegistration"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@id/linearLayoutHoursGuestRegistrationWrapper"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:paddingTop="24dp"
      android:text="Prijavi goste na eVisitor"
      android:textStyle="bold" />

  <ListView
      android:id="@+id/eVisitorGuestsList"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_below="@id/guestsRegisterOnEvisitorLabelGuestRegistration"
      android:layout_margin="10dp"

      android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
      android:background="@color/caldroid_white"
      android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
      android:divider="#CCCCCC"
      android:dividerHeight="1dp"
      android:paddingLeft="2dp"></ListView>

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/newGuestLabelGuestRegistration"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@id/eVisitorGuestsList"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:paddingTop="24dp"
      android:text="Unos novog gosts"
      android:textStyle="bold" />

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/scanDocumentLinearLayoutClickWrapper"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="25dp"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayoutHoursGuestRegistrationWrapper"
      android:layout_alignStart="@+id/linearLayoutHoursGuestRegistrationWrapper"
      android:layout_below="@+id/newGuestLabelGuestRegistration"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding10dp">

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/imageViewScanCardGuestRegistration"
          android:layout_width="25dp"
          android:layout_height="25dp"
          android:adjustViewBounds="true"
          android:background="@drawable/ic_image_white_48dp"
          android:backgroundTint="#d50000" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textViewScanCardGuestRegistration"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:allowUndo="false"
          android:text="Skeniraj osobnu iskaznicu"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
          android:textColor="#d50000" />
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/enterNewGuestLinearLayoutClickWrapper"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="25dp"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayoutHoursGuestRegistrationWrapper"
      android:layout_alignStart="@+id/linearLayoutHoursGuestRegistrationWrapper"
      android:layout_below="@+id/scanDocumentLinearLayoutClickWrapper"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding10dp">

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/imageViewEnterGuestRegistration"
          android:layout_width="25dp"
          android:layout_height="25dp"
          android:adjustViewBounds="true"
          android:background="@drawable/ic_create_black_48dp"
          android:backgroundTint="#d50000" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textViewEnterGuestRegistration"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:allowUndo="false"
          android:text="Upiši novog gosta"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
          android:textColor="#d50000" />
  </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```